# AltGr button selects the input field content

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, firefox

In some website, when I have to enter my e-mail address, I have to use the AltGr key to print the at symbol.
The problem is, on some websites, when I push on AltGr, it selects all the content of the field. Therefore, when I push on `@`, all my text is deleted and replace by the at symbol.

It's really annoying because I have to use copy-paste tip or start by the at when I enter my e-mail address.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have exact the same issue!

Comment: I created a bug report just now: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1416046

Comment: Thanks but it's weird, it doesn't happen in every website. I can't reproduce it in every case.

Comment: Can you tell me a website where you can't reproduce it? It happens to me always, aslong as I enter the field with `tab` key.

Comment: It's weird because I guess this issue is solved on my computer. When I wrote this question, I had this problem on this website : https://edumoov.com/users/register
Now, it works well. What happen to you if you try to reproduce it on this website?

Comment: I still have the error even on this website. If I click with the mouse on the field **Nom** then I can enter `test@mail.com`. But if press then the `tab` key to go field **Prénom** then the key `Alt Gr` will select everthing that I wrote in that field. So if I actually type `test@mail.com` it results in `@mail.com`

Comment: I remember I removed AdBlock for µBlock some days ago (because AdBlock gets me a bug). Do you have AdBlock? Or maybe, did you try to reproduce the bug in safe mode?

Comment: Yes I am using Adblocker. I just deinstalled all my Add-Ons and disabled all plugins, restarded, but I still can reproduce this  `tab` + `alt Gr` problem :/

Comment: Did you try to reproduce it on another browser? And what happen with Firefox in safe mode directly?

Comment: it only happens in Firefox, its not happening in Chrome. When I try Firefox in safe mode then I still can reporduce the problem.

Comment: Which version of Firefox do you use?

Comment: I use Mozilla Firefox 56.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Well, I'm stuck! Do you use a laptop or not? Which model? Are you in dual boot?

Comment: I have the issue again! I don't understand why... Do you still have this problem?

Comment: yes I still have the bug in FIrefox Quantum. Maybe you can create an account and confirm the bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1416046

Comment: I also notice this problem with the Alt key.

Comment: BTW: I have a HP 350 G2 Laptop. Which Laptop / PC are you using? Maybe we have a commen component that causes the error, since it does not seem that everyone has this issue.

Comment: I have a Dell Inspiron 15 (5000 Series).

Comment: I was talking on a forum about this bug and a guy did solve this problem by changing his input method from iBus to XIM. It didn't work for me but maybe it can work for you.

Comment: I just installed compizconfig-settings-manager to solve another problem and this one is gone too. Do you still have this problem? Can you try to install compiz to see what happen? In my case, I just activate the smart placement of windows and half an hour after that, I saw my AltGr problem was gone.

Comment: Okay... it's weird. This morning, after booting my computer, I wanted to check if this problem was still solved and surprised ... it's not! I have this issue again. So I did the manipulation with compiz again and it resolved my problem again. I hope I will not have to do it after every boot.

Answer (score 1):

The permanent Workaround is to select input method "None" in system option ▸ languages ▸ Keyboard Input system.

This does not have a negative impact if you don't need interactive keyboard input like it is necessary for chinese and other scripts.

Source: longstanding unity bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1484157

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Perfect, worked for me! I had an issue where when entering the `@` symbol in the Thunderbird email address input field (AltGr+Q on a German keyboard), the entire field's contents were selected, thus removing everything else in the field after the next key press. Note that you have to logout+login (or reboot) to make the fix work.